# I was banned for 10 years in 2011, can my wife apply for UK business Visa having my name on the list as dependant but am not applying

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I was banned for 10 years in 2011, can my wife apply for UK business Visa having my name on the list as dependant but am not applying.

My school agent use counterfeit documents for me after I paid all the necessary fee to him then.

Can I be listed as a dependant, but am not applying with her and the children.

Won't I affect the application?

Comment: There is no such thing as a UK business visa.

Comment: You may wish to mention what country you are entering the UK *from*.

Comment: @Traveller: Entrepreneur visa

Comment: @Jezella Again, no such visa exists https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur

Comment: @Traveller, am talking an Innovator visa, and the question is that would my visa ban have effect on the application or not.